How to implement in Nuxt.js 2 a URL that displays either a PC or mobile UI based on the device
All mobile pages are placed in the pages/mobile folder; all PC pages are placed in the pages/pc folder.
If accessing from a mobile device, remove the route prefix /mobile for mobile pages and add the route prefix /pc for PC pages.
If accessing from a PC, remove the route prefix /pc for PC pages and add the route prefix /mobile for mobile pages.
